# Search a row with the same value, then divide an other cell in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I try to be as simple as possible.

I have an Excel workbook, with 2 sheets. At the very end, I will need a %, that is divided by 2 specific values.

My problem is, that there is a lot of information in the Excel sheet, and I need to aware of 2 columns at least... let me show:

[image: Example]

As you see, my table looks like this. It is a really really long report, because you can see, there is 24 row for 1 specific time (10:00), and it is generated in every 5 minutes, soooo it is long as hell...

1. column: 10:00 (time)
2. column: 1 (type)
3. column: A, B, C, D, T (type 2)
4. column: not important
5. column: total amount

As you see, I need to be aware of the time, the type, the type 2.

As I told you, I need a % as the following:

```
 10:00  1   A   1   ***5***
 10:00  1   T   1   ***100***
```

So the result should be 5%, because 5 is the 5% part of the 100. So the divide is in this case: 5/100*100.

BUT the time need be the same (10:00), the type (1) need to be the same. And this 5% need to be copied to another cell. It is critical, that I need to divide the same types.

I hope it was understandable, because I really don't have any idea, how can I handle this. I tried with VBA, but I wasn't able to create a proper formula for this a well.

Can you assist? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: The same type according to the number (type 1) or according to the letter (type 2)?

Comment: I agree with @Ralph. Also I would add two comments: 1) a more variable example would be great for understanding the problem, because right now all types have the same sequence `5,2,4,3,100`. 2) It seems to me that this is a problem of logic, not code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments!

Comment: Armin, I would like to help you out. Could you please add a step by step algorithm for atleast 3 unique rows. It would be helpful !!